# How to not show sleep deprivation at work?

Tags: appearance

For the last couple of days, I have been having great trouble sleeping at 'normal' hours. I feel it is starting to affect my work, as greater headaches are starting to climb through the painkillers.

That, however, is not the problem. I am sure I can get this issue under control soon enough, but what strategies can I employ to not have my current state of sleep deprivation show in the office? I work in an IT environment where I share a room with 7 others in a dual-island structure, so I cannot avoid sitting across people and needing to engage in casual development meetings.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am personally of the (potentially misguided) mentality that as long as you can do any work, you should. A sick day had therefore not even come to mind yet. It may be an option, but a tough one to explain - managers here tend to do extensive follow-up on such things. Not at all a coffee drinker either, I tend to get by on water. Haven't seen a doctor in years.

Comment: It's very likely you're getting worse headaches from the painkillers. Regardless, sleep deprivation shouldn't be hidden; it should be dealt with. Suffering from it very bad myself previously, the method that worked for me was to start going to bed at the exact same time every night. Getting the correct sleep routine should fix your problems; it seemed to "reset" me completely and now I can function very well regardless of what time or how many hours I sleep. Good luck!

Comment: Lack of sleep will kill you.  Find a solution to this problem as @JoeStrazzere pointed out.

Comment: Take a day off, doesn't have to be sick. It can be a planned holiday. Get some proper rest. If you don't you'll end up taking sick days. You'll burn out.

Comment: Yawn, Yawn all you can. Yawns are contagious. Bring the whole office down to your tiredness level. When this is achieved then there is no need to hide it.

Comment: @Snowlockk Yawning makes people tired? I've never noticed. I always experienced the opposite effect actually.

Comment: Just tested it. My whole office is semi comatose and yawning with me.

Comment: The medical answer to your question is **low carbohydrates, high protein, high (high quality) fat (so, top quality plain greek yoghourt),and a good amount of water**.  however as everyone has said, it's a bit bizarre.  if you're sick in some way, take a sick day.  but being tired is something of a badge of honor with programmers, you're worrying about nothing.

Comment: Oh, and the way to fix sleep problems is very straightforward: "sleep hygiene" (google it up) and **exercise until you're shredded**.  Finish work this afternoon, go for a 3 hours (very vigorous) walk, eat as outlined, then take a one hour jog, then shower and read a book while falling asleep.  Even if you're "preoccupied" with some life problems, you'll be 100% tomorrow, guaranteed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a tough one to "hide" as there are quite a few symptoms that are visible and you can't really do much about them.

What you can do though is:

- Stay hydrated - drink plenty of water, this will not only help you feel better but reduces some of the visible symptoms as well. Will also help with the headaches!
- Eye-drops/eye "mist" spray - this will help reduce the bloodshot effect you get from lack of sleep
- Caffeine eye-roll-on - various brands do something along these lines. You rub it under your eyes and it helps reduce the darkening and "bags" under the eyes.

May I ask *why* you're so keen to hide it? If you're in work and getting the work done does it really matter if people know you're a bit tired?

Really the goal should be to fix whatever is causing your sleep problems. Living with sleep deprivation is horrendous (there is a reason why it has been used as torture!) and if it goes on long enough it can start having really severe effects not only on your quality of life but your health as well. Please, please don't just ignore it!

Comment: I am keen to hide it in a "keep your private life private" sort of sense. I am quite sure I can have it under control in a couple more days.

Comment: I can understand that.. I'm a pretty private quy myself. Just make sure that if it persists past the natural "reset" of the weekend that you don't let it slide (apologies if that sounds a bit "mother hen" :D)

Comment: **Really the goal should be to fix whatever is causing your sleep problems**  totally true.

Answer (score 5):

Visit your doctor.

This will have two effects; firstly, it may identify the actual problem you're suffering from (or confirm what you *believe* you're suffering from), and secondly, you will have a record of seeking a solution to your problem.

There's a big difference between "I can't sleep", and "I have xxxx, I'm working with my doctor on it". For the first, your colleagues might think you're out partying every night, while the second shows that it's definitely medically related.